# What's the time complexity of character computational algorithms?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, computational-complexity

I couldn't find any information on the time complexity of the Burnside and Dixon-Schneider algorithms and I was wondering if this is well-known? In his paper, Schneider actually includes a table containing certain groups of large order and the CPU-time required by his newly presented algorithm opposed to the one implemented by Dixon, but it would be interesting to see their time complexities anyways.

Thanks in advance!